# Is there a simple way to create a table showing weekly Cost-per-Sales grouped by age and geo?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, average, date-arithmetic

the created table ultimately needs to look like this (where the numbers under the weeks are Cost-per-Sale

```
|Age Group | Geo  | Week 38 | Week 39 | Week 40 |
|      1   |  A   | 13      | 16      | 19      |
|      2   |  A   | 20      | 23      | 28      |
|      1   |  B   | 7       | 9       | 6       |
```

The underlying data looks like this Sale_Id, cost, date, age group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for conditional aggregation. This works to pivot your dataset over a fixed list of weeks:

```
select age_group, geo,
    avg(cost) filter(where extract(week from date) = 38) as week_38,
    avg(cost) filter(where extract(week from date) = 39) as week_39,
    avg(cost) filter(where extract(week from date) = 40) as week_40
from mytable
group by age_group, geo
```

Postgres' weeks are ISO, that is the first week on the year starts on Monday and contains January 4th.